# Altium: priorities not respected?

Tags: altium, design-rules

I'm designing a board with an inverted F antenna. This antenna is connected to a ground plane.
I added a specific polygon plane called "Antenna_GND" aligned with the ground pads of the antenna component.
I defined a specific rule for this polygon with clearance = 0.

Here's the result with only this single rule activated:

[image]

It looks nice to me (the thin black line beetween the polygon and gnd pads is only a display artifact due to the null clearance (I checked in gerbers)).

Now here the result if I activate the general rule (all polygons, clearance 0.15mm):
[image]

The [documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-dlg-priorityeditor-formedit-rule-priorities-ad?version=20.2) states that:

> The situation may be that a design object is covered by more than one rule with the same scope. In this instance, a contention exists. All contentions are resolved by the priority setting. The system goes through the rules from highest to lowest priority and picks the first one whose scope expression(s) match the object(s) being checked.

Althought priority is lower, it seems that the 0.15 rule is applied.

Here's the applicable unary rules for the plane. Looks good to me.
[image]

Do you think it's a bug or a misunderstanding?
What should I do?

Comment: Did you check if the selection you made for the scope actually covers these objects?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the applicable unary rules. Hope I understood well what you meant.

Comment: The easy solution is use a copper region instead of a polygon. Then it will just take the shape you give it and there are no clearances to worry about.